# Removing All Packages With Defunct Dependees in PIP

Tags: python, django, pip

I am wondering if there is a way to uninstall packages in PIP including those that are not listed in the `requirements.txt` but which were installed as dependencies of those that are.

For example, suppose I have `Django==2.1` line in `requirements.txt`.  When running `pip install -r requirements.txt`, the above will instruct PIP to install many extra packages on which Django depends.

However, if I then execute `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt`, the Django package will be uninstalled, but PIP will retain many of its now unused dependencies.

My question is how to go about cleaning those up nicely. Is there a way to make PIP preserve and consider history explicitly? If the thing which forced PIP to install a package is being uninstalled, it appears that we should also be able to flag it to wipe its now defunct dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) Python package and `pipdeptree --reverse some_package` command in particular.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to use [pip-autoremove](https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove). After installing it via `pip`, you can simply call the following from the command line:

```
pip-autoremove Django
```

Which uninstalls Django and its unused dependencies including those not listed in `requirements.txt`.